# Qual a diferença entre onDestroy e a função retornada pelo callback de onMount no Svelte?

Tags: javascript, svelte

O Svelte fornece a função `onMount`, que é executado logo após a renderização do componente e recebe uma função por parâmetro:

```
onMount(() => { console.log('hello') })
```

Caso a função de argumento retorne uma outra função, esta será executada quando o componente estiver prestes a ser destruído:

```
onMount(() => { return () => { console.log('xau') } })
```

Porém, existe também o método `onDestroy`, que funciona igual ao `onMount`, exceto pelo fato de ser executado no final do ciclo de vida do componente:

```
onDestroy(() => { console.log('xau') })
```

Existe alguma diferença entre usar a função retornada pelo *callback* de `onMount` e o `onDestroy`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## *Callback* de destruição via `onMount`

A função de ciclo de vida `onMount` agenda um *callback* para ser executado assim que o componente tiver sido montado no DOM.

Opcionalmente, se esse *callback* retornar uma outra função, esta será utilizada como *callback* para o momento  o componente estiver sendo desmontado. Ela é executada quando o componente é desmontado.

Uma peculiaridade do `onMount` é que ele não é executado se o Svelte estiver rodando no servidor (no contexto dos componentes *server-side*). Portanto, a função de desmonte do `onMount` **não** será executada do lado do servidor.

- [Referência do `onMount`.](https://svelte.dev/docs#onMount)

## *Callback* de destruição via `onDestroy`

É basicamente a mesma coisa que o anterior, mas existem duas diferenças.

Ao contrário do *callback* de destruição criado por `useMount`, que roda rudante o processo de destruição do componente, o *callback* agendado pelo `onDestroy` é executado **antes** que o desmonte sequer comece.

Portanto, `onDestroy` sempre será executado **antes** do *callback* de destruição criado pelo `onMount`.

Uma outra diferença é que o `onDestroy` é executado por componentes sendo executados no lado do servidor. Portanto, são necessários em alguma funcionalidade voltada ao SSR.

- [Referência do `onDestroy`.](https://svelte.dev/docs#onDestroy)

---

## Demonstração

[Deixei um exemplo no Svelte REPL.](https://svelte.dev/repl/422dd24229ae4c67a20dfe2ab016d403?version=3.38.2)

Repare que, quando o componente é desmontado, as mensagens no console são impressas na seguinte ordem:

1. Componente destruído! (via `onDestroy`)
2. Componente destruído! (via `onMount`)

O que demonstra o comportamento da ordem de execução acima descrito.

Comment: Perfeito! Só recomendo que substitua a palavra `construido` por `destruído` no trecho dentro de onMount: `return () => console.log('Componente construído! (via onMount)');` por que as vezes até as mínimas coisas podem causar confusão.

Comment: @yoyo, realmente, foi uma confusão minha. Quis dizer "destruído" mesmo. Obrigado pelo aviso. :) Amanhã apagarei este meu comentário.

Answer (score 3):

A diferença é que a função retornada pelo callback do `onMount`:

```
onMount(() => {
    console.log('Componente montado')

    /* função que será executada após a destruição do componente: */
    return () => {console.log('Componente já foi destruído')}
})
```

será executada **após** o componente ter sido desmontado, enquanto a função descrita dentro do`onDestroy`:

```
onDestroy(() => {
    console.log('O componente está prestes a ser destruído')
})
```

é executado imediatamente **antes** de ele ser destruído. Como é dito na própria [documentação do onMount](https://svelte.dev/docs#onMount), e [do onDestroy](https://svelte.dev/docs#onDestroy)

Comment: Eu li outra coisa, eu li que o onMount é executado quando MONTADO e não quando DESmontado, já o onDestroy é quando é desmontado. Também não foi respondido sobre o `{ return () => { ... })`

Comment: Guilherme, como dito na resposta, a **função retornada pelo onMount**, e não o onMount em si, é que é executada no fim do ciclo. Deve ter ficado pouco claro, então vou editar pra evitar a confusão

Comment: Entendi, acho que precisa elaborar melhor a resposta, o porque disso existir dessa forma por exemplo, mas já esta claro +1

Comment: Só pra constar, na documentação esta escrito WHEN e não AFTER, é exatamente "após"?

Comment: Sim! está escrito `[...]it will be called when the component is unmounted.` que seria `será chamada quando o componente estiver desmontado`, ou seja, o componente foi destruído, logo o método é chamado. Na descrição do `onDestroy` temos: `run immediately before the component is unmounted.`, ouseja, `roda imediatamente antes do componente ser desmontado`